# How to work with navigaionProperties in BreezeMongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, breeze

Currently, I have 2 entities Hospital and Patient with one to many relationship, I created metadata for it as:

```
function addHospital() {
            addType({
                name: 'Hospital',
                autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
                dataProperties: {
                    _id: { type: ID },
                    hospitalID: { type: ID },
                    name: { max: 100 },
                    shortName: { max: 100 },
                    description: { max: 255 },
                    otherInfo: { max: 255 },
                    createdDate: { type: DATE },
                    updatedDate: { type: DATE },
                    createBy: { type: ID },
                    updateBy: { type: ID },
                    stastusID: { type: LUID }
                    ////,patients: {complex:'Patient', hasMany:true}
                },

                navigationProperties: {
                    patients: { type: 'Patient', hasMany: true },
                    //hospitalPatientMap: { type: 'HospitalPatientMap', hasMany: true },
                }
            });
        }

        function addPatient() {
            addType({
                name: 'Patient',
                autoGeneratedKeyType: breeze.AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity,
                dataProperties: {
                    _id: { type: ID },
                    patientID: { type: ID },
                    firstName: { max: 100 },
                    lastName: { max: 100 },
                    middleName: { max: 255 },
                    hospitalID: { type: ID, required: true },
                    mrn: { max: 255 },
                    dateOfBirth: { type: DATE },
                    otherInfo: { max: 255 },
                    createdDate: { type: DATE },
                    updatedDate: { type: DATE },
                    createBy: { type: ID },
                    updateBy: { type: ID },
                    stastusID: { type: LUID }
                },
            });
        }
```

They can CRUD with Nodejs/MongoDB/Breeze properly but seems it doesn't implement navigationProperties for Hospital.
i.e: I have a Patient with exactly have HospitalID that relative with a Hospital:
[image]

I tried to expand('patiens')

```
EntityQuery.from('Hospital').expand('patients')
            .toType('Hospital')
            .using(this.manager).execute()
            .then(querySucceeded).catch(self._queryFailed);
```

but it throws error that BreezeMongo doesn't support expand
[image]

Actually, I can get patients for hospitalID like this:

```
EntityQuery.from('Patient')
          .where('hospitalID', 'eq', hospitalID).using(this.manager).execute()
            .then(success)
            .catch(queryFailed);
```

But this way is not good, we have to make a call to get relative entity everytime we want to use.

Is there an alternative way that we can load navigationProperites into entity (something like eager loading)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent of the breeze "expand" syntax in Mongo. i.e there is nothing like a relational join in Mongo. So breeze has no easy way to perform such a query.

Typically if you have data that is conceptually contained by other data, then the standard 'NoSQL' suggestion is that you model it in as a containment relationship. i.e. make 'patients' a 'collection property' of each 'hospital' and store your data this way.

This property would then be modeled in breeze as a 'complex array' dataProperty named 'patients' of the 'hospital' entity type ( which you have commented out in your example above - modified slightly). ( The syntax below hasn't been checked but it is close, and doesn't use the MetadataHelper code ).

```
,patients: { complexTypeName:'Patient', isScalar: false  }
```

In this case whenever you query a hospital the 'patients' will automatically be brought down as well.

You will also need to model your 'patient' type as a breeze ComplexType as opposed to an EntityType. ComplexTypes are conceptually different in that they do NOT have keys and instances are never shared between entities. This concept maps directly to Mongo collection properties.

Take a look at the Metadata representation in the Zza sample in the Breeze.js.samples GitHub repo.  This is a Mongo sample that has such relationships.

Personally, I would love it if Mongo were to add support for the idea of some sort of relational query operators, but in general this is viewed as a nonstarter in the Mongo community insofar as queries of this form would of necessity be much much slower.

Answer (score 0):

Modeling relationships is a tricky business in NoSQL databases. Most, like MongoDb, do not support relationships.

Sometimes the modeling is easy because you know you want aggregates-with-embedded-entities (e.g., Order with nested OrderDetails). Such an object is best modeled in Breeze with ComplexTypes as Jay says.

But you can't do that everywhere or you'd have one giant aggregate called the database :-)

When a related entity is not part of the aggregate (e.g. Customer and Order are related, separate aggregates), most folks try to split the difference. They'll de-normalize and copy the most frequently used values from Customer into Order. That way, we usually can avoid the extra trip to the server to get order's related customer ... or at least postpone that trip.

Of course to make this work, you have to know how Order will be consumed. You want to copy just the right stuff to Order.

This means you'll spend much more time tailoring your MongoDb to your client workflow scenarios than you would if you were using a relational database.

Because your client requirements change over time, you're under continuous pressure to re-shape your NoSQL db. You are plagued by regret as the years roll on. IMO this is the most critical negative of NoSQL ... and one that is insufficiently discussed because most NoSQL projects are so young and people have trouble looking ahead.

Stepping off my soap box ... what advice do we have for you?

There may be advantage to having BOTH the complex type Jay is talking about AND the navigation property. Let me explain with Order and Customer.

I'd probably denormalize a part of the Customer into the Order as a nested object. On the breeze client I'd have a `customerInfo` property that returns a `CustomerInfo` complex type featuring the customer's `companyName` and whatever else I typically displayed in an listing of orders.

Then I'd have an `Order.CustomerId` property which serves as an FK for the `Order.Customer` navigation property. This will probably be empty when I retrieve the Order. But it's available so I can later call `order.entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty('customer').then(...);` to fill it in.

I'll probably be lucky too. There's an excellent chance I retrieved the orders *after* searching first for their parent customer. That means the customer is already in cache and I can rely on breeze to hook them up to their related child orders for me automatically.

If I think my client app would perform better, I'd consider writing a server-side endpoint (`OrdersWithCustomers`) that combined the Order and related Customer *in the same payload*. Such an endpoint would:

- Get the requested order(s)
- Make a separate request to get the related customer(s)
- Stuff the customer into the Order.Customer property of each order
- Send this synthetic aggregate down to the client.

Breeze will know what to do with it ... if I give it the right guidance (more on that another time). Breeze can extract the customer data in the `Order.Customer` property and put it in cache for me automatically.